Calculate angle $x$ in the triangle $ABC$ below
Calculate $x^o$ if $AB = AN$.
(*If necessary, it is possible to use approximate right triangles.)
(Answer:$30^o$)

I try:
$\angle B = 180^o -24^o - 48^o = 108^o $
$\triangle ABN: \angle ABN \cong \angle ANB = \frac{180^o -24^o }{2}= 78^o $
$\therefore \angle CNB = 180^o 78^o = 102^o $
$\angle NBC = 180^o - 102^o -48^o =30^o  $
$\angle CNM= \angle x+ 6^o $


Solution:
Construct $\triangle DAN$ as a equilateral triangle, where $D,B$ are on the same side of $AC$. Notice that $\angle ABC=180^\circ-24^\circ-48^\circ=108^\circ$. Also, $\angle DAB=60^\circ-\angle BAC=36^\circ$. Since $AB=AN=AD$ we have $\angle DBA=\angle BDA=72^\circ$. Therefore, $D,B,M$ are collinear. Thus, $\angle MDA=72^\circ$. Since $\angle MAN=6^\circ$ we have $\angle DAM=60^\circ-6^\circ=54^\circ$ and thus $\angle DMA=54^\circ$ hence $DA=DM=DN$. So, $\angle AMN=\angle DMN-\angle CMA=(90^\circ-\angle ADM/2)-(90^\circ-\angle MDN/2)=\angle ADN/2=30^\circ$.


Another approach:
Consider following picture. You found $\angle NBC=30^o$. D, the center of circumcircle of triangle NBC is the intersection of bisector of angle  BAC and the circumcircle of triangle ABN, hence $DN\bot AC$. DN is almost perpendicular on MM' that is:
$arc M'N\approx arc MN$
$\rightarrow \angle AMN\approx \angle NBC=30^o$

Thanks for help
